# How to pass an entry to doctl compute volume delete?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

With the command

```
(doctl compute volume list) | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tail -n +2
```

I have got a list of all volumes that I have created on DO. Now I would like to delete all volumes. With the command `doctl compute volume delete`, a volume can be deleted.

I am trying to run:

```
(doctl compute volume list) | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tail -n +2 | doctl compute volume delete
```

Unfortunately it shows me:

```
Error: (volume.delete) command is missing required arguments
```

How pipe it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relpace

```
doctl compute volume delete
```

with

```
xargs -n 1 doctl compute volume delete
```